# SEO Google Sub Menu

Tags: seo

Did anybody know
when i make search with keyword "**internetdownloadmanager**"
there is will be sub menu for the page of 
[www.internetdownloadmanager.com](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/)

like

- Download
- Registration
- Internet Download Manager ...
- Internet Download Manager screenshot

can somebody tell me how to make something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add those yourself. However, if Google has added those links for your site under one or more search terms, you **can selectively remove them** through the Google Webmaster portal - but **you cannot add them yourself** -- that is determined by Google and its algorithms.

More info: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334